# Why can't I access any properties on my jQuery-returned object?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have the following javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').disabled = $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').selectedIndex != 1;
    });
});
```

When I change the index of the dropdown, nothing happens. I have tried to replace the code with:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function() {
        alert($('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').id);                    
    });
});
```

This generates an alert that says 'undefined'. If I remove the .id-part I get an alert that says [object Object] so I guess it has got something. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For ASP.NET ids, as they exist on the client page, you can usually do something like this in jQuery: $('input[id$=TextBox1'). It matches the  end of the ID, which is always the same as the ID you gave to the element in ASP.NET. It's cleaner than putting <% %> in your js code.

Comment: I did not get that to work. Did you miss any characters from that code?

Comment: I'm sorry, that did work. What I didn't get to work was $('input[id$= DropDownList1') but if I changed it to just $('[id$= DropDownList1') it works great. For some reason "input" doesn't work with asp.net drop down lists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One key thing to realize in jQuery is that what is returned by the $(selector) is a jQuery object, not the DOM object.  If you want to get the value for the select box from the jQuery object, you can use the val() function as in:

```
$("#element").val();
```

If you want to access the dom element from the jQuery object, that is easy, too.  You can use the following:

```
$("#element")[0]; // equivalent to $("#element").get(0)
```

That should help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').change(function()
    {
        // replace 'your value' with the value of dropdown selectedIndex 1
        if ($('#<%= DropDownList1.ClientID %>').val() == 'your value')
            $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').removeAttr('disabled');
        else
            $('#<%= TextBox1.ClientID %>').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    });
});
```